# Ubuntu UI laptop/ touch

Tags: keyboard, ubuntu-touch, touchpad, tablet, multi-touch

First post but longtime Ubuntu user!

So about two yars ago I bought an Acer Aspire R14 laptop, which has a touch screen and can flip around to a tablet and be all fancy. The problem I have always had was I never used the tablet version because once you flip it around to the tablet, the User Interface fundamentally changes from that of a pointer/ keyboard interface to a finger dependent one but the interface remains that of the pointer/ keyboard.

My dream is that once you flip into tablet the OS/ UI/ theme/ whatever changes to something like a smart phone/ ipad/ Ubuntu touch (yeah i know its dead), something with big icons for my fat fingers, easy navigation, simplified/ clean access and usability. Or even a separate OS so you have a choice of which UI to boot up. I am aware of a few little things you can do like the onboad keyboard etc, but I'm looking for something completely fluid.

I guess my question is, is anyone working on something like this? or is there an app/ simple workaround? I'm not really sure how to search for something like this, or what questions to ask, any recommendations? Thanks!